# Why need Objective-C bridging header in swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new in swift . I crated a swift project and I try to added `NSmanagedObject subclass` for core data 
but xcode telling  me **Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?**

what should i do ? and why ?

[image]

**Flowing step I done :**

create a  single page application 
[image]

then try to add subclass 
[image]

then select the entity would i mange

[image]

then create 
[image]

last things why added +coredatapropertice

[image]

Comment: If you want to use an Objective-C class in swift project. Than it will be need

Comment: @iDeveloper can you check my update question

Comment: Have you set Click CoreData at Project Creation time ?

Comment: @iDeveloper no don't do that

Comment: So i request you, Please create a new project and set core data than no need to bridge.

Comment: yea new project and set core data and no need bridge.  can you check my last scene

Comment: [Click Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) You need to see this.

Comment: @iDeveloper how can add core data feature existing project

Comment: I hope [Demo 1](http://purelywebdesign.co.uk/tutorial/add-coredata-to-an-exiting-swift-2-0-project/) OR [Demo 2](http://www.codebeaulieu.com/10/adding-core-data-using-swift-2) one of them will helpful for you

Comment: @iDeveloper yea thank you so much. I love you .

Comment: MoSt wElcOmE. Enjoy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode is asking you if you'd like to create a bridging header because you are adding Objective-C files to a Swift project.

Since your project is written in Swift, I'm guessing that you meant to select 'Swift' as the language when creating your NSManagedObject subclasses.

[image]

Comment: you got exact problem is ? i fixed it by this way . and i came beck here post my answer . ok no problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

This way to gain access to a library is to use the Objective-C bridging header. Since Objective-C is a superset of C, the bridging header also works to give you access to pure C libraries. 
This allow you to add the Objective-C  file in our swift project

Comment: can check my Update question